# Access elements in a form (or other containing element) using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `form` element which contains a bunch of `input` elements (however, I expect it would be the same if instead of a `form`, the inputs were in a given `div`) .  JavaScript needs the the values within the form multiple times.  Instead of using a bunch of `var id=$('#id').val();` script, how can I grab everything in the form, and then use the values like `mainForm.id`?

```
<form method="post" id="mainForm">
    <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input id="cid" name="cid" value="pages" type="hidden" />
    <input id="task" name="task" value="delete" type="hidden" />
    <input id="controller" name="controller" value="display" type="hidden" />
    <input id="CSRF" name="CSRF" value="123" type="hidden">
</form>
```

EDIT

Not perfect, but maybe just:

```
var obj=document.getElementById('mainForm');

console.log(obj.id.value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an empty object , utilizing `$.each()` to populate object with property `id` of `input` , object value with `value` of `input`

```js
var obj = {};

$.each($("#mainForm input"), function(key, val) {
  obj[val.id] = val.value
});

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<form method="post" id="mainForm">
  <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input id="cid" name="cid" value="pages" type="hidden" />
  <input id="task" name="task" value="delete" type="hidden" />
  <input id="controller" name="controller" value="display" type="hidden" />
  <input id="CSRF" name="CSRF" value="123" type="hidden">
</form>
```

---

Without jQuery

```js
var obj = {};
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("#mainForm input");
[].forEach.call(inputs, function(val, key) {
  obj[val.id] = val.value;
});

console.log(obj)
```

```html
<form method="post" id="mainForm">
  <input id="id" name="id" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input id="cid" name="cid" value="pages" type="hidden" />
  <input id="task" name="task" value="delete" type="hidden" />
  <input id="controller" name="controller" value="display" type="hidden" />
  <input id="CSRF" name="CSRF" value="123" type="hidden">
</form>
```

Comment: Makes an array of objects, not a single object with properties of either the name or id (which happens to always be the same)

Comment: @user1032531 Is expected result single object with `id`:`value` of each `input` ?

Comment: Looking for `{id:1,cid:'pages',task:'delete',controller:display, CSRF:123}`.

Comment: Exactly.  Is there a more concise perhaps without jQuery?  I added a not perfect solution to my original post but it is not exact as they will need to be accessed  as `obj.id.value` instead of `obj.id` as ideally.

Comment: Actually, it is pretty concise, and I will likely go with it. Thanks

Comment: @user1032531 _"Exactly. Is there a more concise perhaps without jQuery?"_ See updated post.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#mainForm input').each(function() {
    // do what you want with the input here 
    // console.log($(this).attr('id')); will print the id of every input for example
});
```

Comment: Thanks Bdloul,  I thought there might be a more concise way if I just wanted to set a variable to `{id:1,cid:'pages',task:'delete',controller:`display`, CSRF:123}`. where the property of the object was either the id or name and the value of the property was the value of the input.